# Create a Sharepoint list in a specific folder with Microsoft graph api

Tags: list, microsoft-graph-api

Premise:
I have a folder under the sharepoint site for e.g.
https://... <mycompany-sharepoint-site.com>/
under which we have folder so my url is something like
https://... <mycompany-sharepoint-site.com>/Documents/Sub_folder_1/Sub_folder_2
pertaining to our project.

I need to be able to create a Sharepoint list in the Sub_folder_2 - folder and not at the root level.

With Sharepoint - GraphApi - create list api url

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists)

I will ONLY be able to create at the <mycompany-sharepoint-site.com> level (i.e. at the root level) which is not what I want.

FYI, I already tried (on Postman) to go with the drives//items/<folder_id> - route or I should say attempted to do so but failed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists` can create list in the root folder, so my idea is adding the folder path in the request and try again. according to [this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-path), maybe we can use request like `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/lists` .. just a try. because I don't have sharepoint resource so I can't test in my side.

Comment: @Tiny Wang - your suggestion didn't work as it gives me this error
<p>
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-01-03T14:49:52",
            "request-id": "35a0d462-b225-4e77-b8fa-10278b37f67b",
            "client-request-id": "35a0d462-b225-4e77-b8fa-10278b37f67b"
        }
    }
}
</p>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Graph API to create a folder in SharePoint, please use the following query:

```
POST /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Again @Mehtab Siddique - I am NOT attempting to create a folder. That is not the use case here. I am trying to create a Sharepoint List inside a sub-folder NOT at the root of the company's Sharepoint site. So your suggestion is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that SharePoint supports creating a list inside the folder but you can at least try to create a list and specify the path in the parent reference.

You need to find out the drive id.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists

{
    "displayName": "Test",
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "Column1",
            "text": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "Column2",
            "number": {}
        }
    ],
    "list": {
        "template": "genericList"
    },
    "parentReference": {
        "driveType": "documentLibrary",
        "driveId": "{drive_id}",
        "path": "/drives/{drive_id}/root:/Documents/Sub_folder_1/Sub_folder_2"
        # or
        # "path": "/drives/{drive_id}/root:/Sub_folder_1/Sub_folder_2" 
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't help either, I tried to give the parentReference path both ways. It still creates only in the site root.
Here's partial payload "parentReference": { "driveType": "documentLibrary", "driveId": "...", "path": "/drives/.../root:/Project/Data_Export" }


Response screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJusw.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's even possible at all, did you succeed that manually?